# Spinner Text Not Visible

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to `setText` in `Spinner` but is not visible in device. (Visible in emulater) .

Please give solution for this.

Comment: What have you tried, do you have a code sample, what device are you using etc etc?

Comment: Are they both (device and emulator) running the same API level?

Answer (score 1):

You cant settext to spinner with settext(). You have to use ArrayAdapter for displaying the content in spinner. like this,

Declare an array-

```
String[] type_array = {"Monthly","Quaterly","Yearly"};
```

In onCreate()-

```
spinner_type = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_type_susa);
spinner_type.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_type = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_row,type_array);
adapter_type.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner_type.setAdapter(adapter_type);
```

Comment: If he used setText() with a spinner he wouldn't even be able to compile the code. Vikalp Patel edited the post and used a code block for "set text" but the OP used it in a more generic way I think.

Answer (score 0):

You gave the text a holo color that is only available on a high API level and your device doesn't know what to do with it so it gave the default color of text which is black, which just happens to be the color of the background in your spinner. Yes this is a wild guess.